# Block matrix exponent proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

$A = \begin{bmatrix} B & C \\ 0  & I\end{bmatrix}; \tag{1}$

$B$ and $C$ are $n \times n$ matrices.  Prove that

$A^k =\begin{bmatrix} B^k &  (B^k-I)(B-I)^{-1}C \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}. \tag{2}$

Assume $B-I$ is invertible.

Comment: I edited your question, using $\LaTeX$ to make in more readable. Hope I got the math right and this is OK with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a multiplication by block we get

$$\begin{pmatrix}B&C\\0&I\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}B&C\\0&I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}B&C\\0&I\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}B^2&(B+I)C\\0&I\end{pmatrix}$$

and by induction we have easily

$$\begin{pmatrix}B&C\\0&I\end{pmatrix}^k=\begin{pmatrix}B^k&\sum_{p=0}^{k-1}B^pC\\0&I\end{pmatrix}$$
finally notice that we verify easily 
$$\sum_{p=0}^{k-1}B^p=(B^k-I)(B-I)^{-1}$$

Comment: how did you get the answer to the sum?

Comment: @SamKay post-multiply both sides of the sum relation by $(B-I)$. then you will see why it holds.